# Separate combined header with \cline in \multirow / \multicolumn environment

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow, cline

Hi I am a beginner with tables and I'm struggling to typeset a table beautifully.
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l *{7}{X}}
\toprule
\multirow{4}{*}{Method} & 
\multirow{4}{\linewidth}{Time step} & 
\multirow{4}{\linewidth}{Test calculation} & 
\multirow{4}{\linewidth}{Testing update} &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Test hello-world}\\ \cline{5-8}
& & & & Model B, $x = 42$ & Model B, $y = 42$ & ModelC longword & ModelD wordOne wordTwo\\
\midrule
A & 0.010 & 1 & 0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 \\
B & 0.010 & 2 & 0 & 1.6 & 1.9 & 2.1 & 2.1 \\
C & 0.010 & 1 & 1 & 2.3 & 3.0 & 3.4 & 3.3 \\
D & 0.010 & 1 & 1 & 1.8 & 2.1 & 2.7 & 2.6 \\
E & 0.010 & 1 & 1 & 2.0 & 3.0 & 3.7 & 3.5 \\
F & 0.010 & (2) & 2 & 4.4 & 5.1 & 7.0 & 6.7 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The second row in the table has to little distance to the \cline. Every help to fix this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You are using `booktabs`, did you try using its `\cmidrule`? (instead of `\cline`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are already using `booktabs`, you should use its `\cmidrule` instead of `\cline` to get:

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. I also added `\multirow{4}[3]{*}{Method}` to get the vertical centering for the first 4 columns which is now needed due to `\cmidrule`.